# Why do I get a Java OutOfMemory exception when building a UITest project, even when building in x64 with 2G heap?

Tags: java, android, xamarin, heap-memory, xamarin.uitest

We're developing an Android app using Xamarin. 
We're using Visual Studio Team Services as our CI service.

The project consist of (among other things)

- Droid.csproj (android project)
- UITest.csproj (C# assembly for UI tests)

Recently the Droid.csproj failed the build because of a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error. We changed the configuration of the server to run as x64, and increased the Java Max Heap Size to 2G. I can see in VSTS that the project is now successfully building.

However, the UITest.csproj is failing, with the following:

```
2016-10-13T22:58:49.2048732Z ##[error]COMPILETODALVIK(0,0): Error : 
2016-10-13T22:58:49.2048732Z COMPILETODALVIK : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL error :  [C:\a\1\s\Droid\Mobile.Droid.csproj]
2016-10-13T22:58:49.2048732Z   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2016-10-13T22:58:49.2048732Z    at java.lang.Object.clone(Native Method)
2016-10-13T22:58:49.2048732Z    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1206)
2016-10-13T22:58:49.2048732Z    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:157)
2016-10-13T22:58:49.2048732Z    at com.android.dx.dex.file.MixedItemSection.placeItems(MixedItemSection.java:301)
2016-10-13T22:58:49.2048732Z    at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.toDex0(DexFile.java:541)
2016-10-13T22:58:49.2048732Z    at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.toDex(DexFile.java:214)
2016-10-13T22:58:49.2048732Z    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.writeDex(Main.java:856)
2016-10-13T22:58:49.2048732Z    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:323)
2016-10-13T22:58:49.2048732Z    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
2016-10-13T22:58:49.2048732Z    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
2016-10-13T22:58:49.2048732Z    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

It seems the UITest is dependent on the Droid, which makes sense because it's testing the Droids UI components. Do I need to configure something in the UITest project for this to work?

For reference, this is the project configuration screen for the UITest project: (as you can see, it's an ordinary C# project so there's no option to increase Heap Size)

[image]

Is there something else I need to specify in VSTS for this UITest project to build?

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure that is from the build for the UITest project? When building the UITest project, the Android app project it references should build as well so maybe that is still the Android project build output? Can't tell from what is posted.

Comment: Yeah, i think it's the Droid.csproj that's failing, as it's triggered by the UITest project. When the Droid project builds on its own it's fine, but fails when the UITest triggers it. Whatever the case, we've removed the UITest from the build steps. Hopefully that works

Comment: What build configurations are you using? IIRC you need to set the java heap size for each build configuration, so if you only set it for release and the UITest is building the debug version then you'll get the error